# Find out the DNS server for a DHCP connection in Linux

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dhcp

I know they're defined in `/etc/resolv.conf`, but what if it's not there? And more specifically, how do you find the DNS server returned by DHCP?

In GNOME you can use the NetworkManager applet to see the primary DNS for any connection, so how would you do the same from the command line?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Usually dhclient.leases file is located at `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases`, type the following command:

`less /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases`

OR

`cat /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases`

OR

You can just use grep command to get DHCP server address, enter:

`grep dhcp-server-identifier /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases`

OR

`dhclient eth0`

Comment: Great, thanks! In case anybody looks for this, the IPCop file is found on /var/ipcop/dhcpc/dhcpcd-*.info

Comment: This is specific of one DHCP client but there are others (such as pump).

Comment: I ran `ps aux | grep dhclient` and found that my leases file was set to `/var/run/dhclient.eth0.leases` with the `-lf` option.

Comment: also, `less /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` works for **Ubuntu 22**, while the mentioned in the answer—do not

Answer (score 9):

I recently had this problem where my `dhcpcd` was misconfigured as was not setting DNS servers.  I found out that I can query which nameservers are available by DHCP with the following command:

```
sudo dhcpcd -o domain_name_servers -T
```

The command will output a bunch of network connection information.  Look for the line beginning with `new_domain_name_servers`.

From here I was able to manually set the nameservers.

Comment: Perfect. This should be the accepted answer, hehe.

Comment: This was also the solution that worked for me.

Comment: why `-o` switch is necessary if it dumps all the same options with `-T` alone?

Answer (score 7):

One more solution to query the DHCP server:

```
sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover
```

The output tells you the name server offered by the DHCP server:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-12-12 23:50 UTC
Pre-scan script results:
| broadcast-dhcp-discover: 
|   Response 1 of 1: 
|     IP Offered: 144.123.211.44
|     DHCP Message Type: DHCPOFFER
|     Server Identifier: 144.123.99.200
|     IP Address Lease Time: 5m00s
|     Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
|     Router: 144.123.99.200
|     Domain Name Server: 144.123.99.200
|_    Domain Name: localdomain
```

Answer (score 3):

I found my DHCP lease info at `/var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases` in case anyone can't find it at `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases`

Answer (score 2):

well, why not simply dig that?

```
marcus@marcus ~ $ dig google.de

; <<>> DiG 9.4.3-P3 <<>> google.de
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27579
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.de.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.de.      1785    IN  A   209.85.229.104
google.de.      1785    IN  A   216.239.59.104
google.de.      1785    IN  A   74.125.77.104

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
de.         23431   IN  NS  L.DE.NET.
de.         23431   IN  NS  Z.NIC.de.
de.         23431   IN  NS  F.NIC.de.
de.         23431   IN  NS  C.DE.NET.
de.         23431   IN  NS  S.DE.NET.
de.         23431   IN  NS  A.NIC.de.

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.15#53(192.168.1.15)
;; WHEN: Thu Sep 17 19:33:39 2009
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 181
```

look at the last lines:
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.15#53(192.168.1.15)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing originally, but I don't that that would show ALL of the assigned DNS servers, would it?  I think dig only returns the one it used for that particular lookup.  On second look, the poster didn't specify so if he's happy with it then your answer is definitely the easiest. :-)

Comment: yes you are right output only shows up the dns used by that query... so you can see what __is__ really happening. I found your solution fine to figure out what __should__ happen, thy for that :-)

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but thanks anyway.

Comment: When no DNS server responds, dig doesn't show any useful info, is it possible to make it spit out the DNS servers it tried to ask?

Comment: So after RingTFM, I see it just uses whatever is on /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing in /etc/resolv.conf, DNS resolution (that is, resolution using dns as defined in /etc/nsswitch.conf) will not work. This is what dig, host and the libc routines use to do DNS resolution. If there is nothing specified in this file, DNS resolution will not work (though host resolution may work via other means, if another host resolution method is configured, such as NIS (this is unlikely)).

Answer (score 1):

this command show the DNS server on your net

dig | grep SERVER: | awk -F# '{ print $1 }' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'

172.17.0.1

Comment: This does answer the question. In fact it is less reliable than the approach the OP mentions in the question, which is simply to read it from `/etc/resolv.conf`. After all dig is going to read from `/etc/resolv.conf` as well and then (try to) communicate with the server before producing any output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NetworkManager, to get ipv4 DNS servers for *YourConnectionName* connection, you can use something like

```
nmcli -g IP4.DNS connection show YourConnectionName
```

Use `nmcli connection show YourConnectionName` to get all possible options and values.

Answer (score 0):

Read `/etc/resolv.conf`. That's all.

`man resolv.conf` is useful, too.

Comment: except he said what to do if it's *not* there..

Comment: Yes, but I ignored this point, which makes no sense. Since the libc resolver uses resolv.conf, it has to be there.

Comment: The question said specifically not to use resolve.conf and there is plenty of reasons where resolve.conf is not holding everything (e.g. in my case when a DHCP Server is used)

Answer (score 0):

In modern distributions it is looks like

```
ps aux | grep dhcli | grep -v grep                                                    
root       367  0.0  0.0  16128  3076 ?        S    Apr30   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-enp3s0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-324caec3-58f9-3f00-bff4-2f8bd7d2aafa-enp3s0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-enp3s0.conf enp3s0


tail -16 /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-324caec3-58f9-3f00-bff4-2f8bd7d2aafa-enp3s0.lease
lease {
  interface "enp3s0";
  fixed-address 10.191.104.3;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.191.104.254;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 91.193.220.3,91.193.220.7;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 91.193.220.3;
  option ntp-servers 91.193.220.6;
  option broadcast-address 10.191.104.255;
  option domain-name "myISP.ru";
  renew 1 2017/05/01 12:56:02;
  rebind 2 2017/05/02 00:27:11;
  expire 2 2017/05/02 03:27:11;
}
```

where 91.193.220.7 is my ISP's DNS server

```
nslookup serverfault.com 91.193.220.7
Server:     91.193.220.7
Address:    91.193.220.7#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
```

Answer (score 0):

if use `systremd-resolve`:

```
$ resolvectl status wlp0s20f3 
//OR
$ systemd-resolve --status wlp0s20f3
```

outputs:

```
Link 3 (wlp0s20f3)
      Current Scopes: DNS          
DefaultRoute setting: yes          
       LLMNR setting: yes          
MulticastDNS setting: no           
  DNSOverTLS setting: opportunistic
      DNSSEC setting: no           
    DNSSEC supported: no           
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.27.1 
         DNS Servers: 192.168.27.1 
          DNS Domain: ~.           
                      lan
```

//OR

```
$ resolvectl dns
Global:
Link 5 (tun0): 10.1.2.1
Link 3 (wlp0s20f3): 192.168.1.1
```